Replace subset of dataframe (rows and columns)
I have a dataframe o which contains incorrect data. I have another dataframe r with the correct data. I want to replace the subset of o (both rows and columns) with r. I'm seeking a solution that scales to many variables / columns. (I do have a vector rv with the column names of the variables that need replacing)
o <- tibble(id = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 2), aa = letters[1:6], bb = LETTERS[2:7], cc = 11:16)
r <- tibble(id = c(2,4), cc = c(111, 113), aa = c("aa", "cc"))
rv <- c("aa", "cc")

> o
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     id aa    bb       cc
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     2 a     B        11
2     3 b     C        12
3     4 c     D        13
4     7 d     E        14
5    10 e     F        15
6     2 f     G        16

> r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     id    cc aa   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     2   111 aa   
2     4   113 cc   

I want to end up with (I don't care about the order of rows or columns):
> o
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     id aa    bb       cc
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     2 aa    B       111
2     3 b     C        12
3     4 cc    D       113
4     7 d     E        14
5    10 e     F        15
6     2 aa    G       111

You can assume that all ids in r are in o, but you cannot assume that columns or rows are the in the same order, and there are duplicated id in o (not in r), where the relevant columns should also be overwritten.
I tried base R, but the duplicate id in o stumps it:
 o[o$id %in% r$id, rv] <- r

I thought of dplyr using left_join but don't know how to overwrite rather than attach.
My question is different from similar ones because there are several columns to replace, but not the entire dataset -- on which I had found useful answers.

You can do o |> dplyr::rows_update(r).

OMG thanks! Do you know how many hours I have spent looking for that! Do write it out and I'll accept it.

I have reopened this since none of the purported duplicates are base solutions along the lines of the question's attempt that actually work on this problem.  The only base solution among them does not work with duplicates which is the situation here.

One comment regarding rows_update.  When that function was first released in dplyr it did not handle duplicates so if you want to use it then be sure to use a recent version of dplyr.

If the question is looking for a base R solution that fixes up the attempt in the question then note that we can only write o[...] <- r with just r on the right hand side if it is sufficient to replace just the first occurrence of each id in o. If that were ok then we could fix it like this:
# only replaces first instance of each r id in o
o[match(r$id, o$id), names(r)] <- r

With duplicate id's in o, as in the example data, we will need a loop; however, it is still only one line of code:
# replace all instances of each id so can be used with example data
for(id in r$id) o[o$id == id, names(r)] <- r[r$id == id, ]

An equivalent alternative to the explicit loop is to use Reduce like this:
upd <- function(o, id) {
  o[o$id == id, names(r)] <- r[r$id == id, ]
  o
}
Reduce(upd, r$id, init = o)

